# Change the keyboard shortcuts for moving of the insertion point

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Is there a way to change the behavior of keyboard shortcuts for moving the insertion point (cursor) between words?

What I basically would like to achieve is just to switch the behavior for when <kbd>Command</kbd>  or <kbd>Option</kbd> key is being held:

[image: Keyboard shortcuts according to Apple]

The behavior of those two should be exactly the other way around.